# what is the relationship between File and Writer in Go?

Tags: go

I am just reading up on Go and saw this code

```go
func main(){
s:=`<html>removed content for brevity</html>`
    newfile, err := os.Create("index.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create file with error: %v", err)

    }
    defer newfile.Close()
    _, _ = io.Copy(newfile, strings.NewReader(s))
}
```

According to the documentation, the Copy function first parameter is the Writer interface but I am unable to find any references to this interface when in the File struct documentation.

```go
func Copy(dst Writer, src Reader) (written int64, err error)
```

I am assuming the File struct implements the Writer interface but I would like to know how to identify this type of dependencies as I learn the language?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Create

The `Create()` method from the `os` package returns a `*File` as one of its values.

You can tell that the `File` struct implements the `Writer` interface because it implements the `Write()` method, which, as you guessed, is a requirement for Writers.

**File.Write() implementation**: https://golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Write

**Writer interface**: https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer

You might also want to check out the documentation on interfaces:
https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types

Comment: Thank you, Munsy. The Implicit implementation mechanism Go uses still messes with my head sometimes.